# Python script to get temperature from google search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am making a python script which will get temperature from google by searching for keyword temperature.
I have found that the value of temperature is stored in span id="wob_tm" from this inspect element code->

```
<div>
<div class="vk_bk sol-tmp" style="float:left;margin-top:-3px;font-size:64px"><span id="wob_tm" class="wob_t" style="display:inline">
  18
</span><span id="wob_ttm" class="wob_t" style="display:none"> … </span>
</div>
```

It can be seen that temperature 18 is inside span id="wob_tm".
So ,my python script is->

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,sys,webbrowser    

str="temperature"
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=%s'%str)
res.raise_for_status()
examplesoup= BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")    
linkelems=examplesoup.findAll("span",{"id":"wob_tm"})
print linkelems.string.strip()
```

It gives me this error-
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
How to correct it? That means that linkelems has no  elements.

Comment: Why are you printing the the length of linkelems?

Comment: Just to make sure that the list linkelems has something from which the text is to be extracted.But strangely,it has no elements.

Comment: Why not use a simple free weather API instead of scraping the google page?

Comment: Because It feels good to make something of our own.

Comment: In the weather page i get it has this span id =wob_tm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some experimentation it seems like Google sends slightly different results depending on what browser it thinks you are using.  I see the span with id 'wob_tm' when I use Firefox, for example, but not by default when running your code.  (I do get a span with class wob_t that has the temperature, but I also get 10 other wob_t spans).  Try setting the user agent to a popular browser, like follows:

```
str="temperature"

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'
}

res = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s' % str, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
examplesoup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
linkelems=examplesoup.findAll('span', {'id': 'wob_tm'}) # This now has an element in it
```

Answer (score 0):

The `0` you're printing is the *length* of the span tag's contents, not the contents themselves. The `string` attribute will get you the contents of the div tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div>
<div class="vk_bk sol-tmp" style="float:left;margin-top:-3px;font-size:64px">
<span id="wob_tm" class="wob_t" style="display:inline">
18
</span><span id="wob_ttm" class="wob_t" style="display:none"> … </span>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
temperature = soup.find("span", id="wob_tm")
print(temperature.string.strip())
# 18
```

Comment: Even though i have changes my code as shown above it still gives me error that NoneType object has not attribute named string.

Comment: I think your html is missing an ending ">" for the starting div tag, which is why the span tag (with id "wob_tm") is not being recognized

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code (using Python 3 and bs4) and got the string of the span tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_snippet = """<div>
<div class="vk_bk sol-tmp" style="float:left;margin-top:-3px;font-size:64px"><span id="wob_tm" class="wob_t" style="display:inline">18</span><span id="wob_ttm" class="wob_t" style="display:none"> ... </span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_snippet)
temp = soup.find("span", id='wob_tm')

print(temp.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `user-agent` so Google don't treat you request as a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814), which is default `requests` `User-Agent`. You can use `.select_one()` `bs4` method if you need to extract only temperature data.

```py
>>> soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
'85°F'
```

Code and example which extracts more [in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Weather-Answer-Box-bs4-python-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "london weather",
  "hl": "en",
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

tempature = soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
print(f'Tempature: {tempature}')

---
# Tempature: 73°F
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "london weather",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

loc = results['answer_box']['location']
weather_date = results['answer_box']['date']
weather = results['answer_box']['weather']
temp = results['answer_box']['temperature']
unit = results['answer_box']['unit']
precipitation = results['answer_box']['precipitation']
humidity = results['answer_box']['humidity']
wind = results['answer_box']['wind']

forecast = results['answer_box']['forecast']

print(f'{loc}\n{weather_date}\n{weather}\n{temp}\n{unit}\n{precipitation}\n{humidity}\n{wind}\n{forecast}')

---------
'''
London, UK
Wednesday 1:00 PM
Partly cloudy
73°F
0%
55%
7 mph

[{'day': 'Wednesday', 'weather': 'Partly cloudy', 'temperature': {'high': '74', 'low': '59'}, 'thumbnail': 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/weather/48/partly_cloudy.png'}..]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.